# Dismiss Game Center view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, game-center

I implemented Game Center into an iOS app.

When the game center leader board view is opened from within the app and I press the 'Done' button, the view doesn't disappear.

**Below the code to open the Game Center view:**

```
        GKGameCenterViewController gameCenter = new GKGameCenterViewController ();

        gameCenter.ViewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards;
        gameCenter.LeaderboardCategory = "myleaderboardddd";
        gameCenter.LeaderboardTimeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScope.AllTime;

        gameCenter.Finished += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine ("CLOSE THIS VIEW!");   // <-- THIS IS NEVER REACHED
            this.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };

        this.PresentViewController (gameCenter, true, null);
```

Note that the Console.WriteLine is never reached when pressing the done button.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is identical to a bug report we had recently. This was fixed but it might not be released yet (in stable 6.2.x releases).

You might want to *try* the latest beta (6.3.x) version. It will have the fix (if only to confirm that the fix is coming and that this is not a different issue).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and let you know.

Comment: The beta version (6.3.x) solved the problem! Thank you. Do you also know an answer for my other Game center problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262085/only-one-player-displayed-in-game-center-leader-board-sandbox

Comment: Glad to hear it :-) The next (non hotfix) release of 6.2.x (stable) will have the same fix. Sadly I do not know the answer to your other question, I never made a game (with or without GameKit) on iOS. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.