# Only one player displayed in Game Center leader board (Sandbox)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, sandbox, game-center, gamekit

In the sandbox environment of Game Center I tested with 2 different users. Unfortunately I only see one player in the leader board. Only the player who is logged in.

I thought it should update after a while but now (24 hours later) I still only see one user in the leader board.

Is this correct in the sandbox environment?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it takes more than 24 hours to update the leader board.

After +/- 48 hours, the other user also disappeared in the Game Center Leaderboard.